# StreamingContext with filter in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I used StreamingContext of Scala with success to count words:

```
val scc = new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(1))
val dstream = scc.textFileStream("""file:///pathToDirectoryWindows""");
//dstream is DStream[String] 
val words = dstream.flatMap(line=>line.split(" "));
```

But the I tried to do the same with filtering, that is taking into account only files with extention .txt. It seems textFileStream does not allow filter, so I tried fileStream:

```
val fstream=scc.fileStream("""file:///pathToFolderWin""",x=>x.getName().contains(".txt"), true);
```

But this time I cannot split, because the result is not DStream[String], but inputDStream[(Nothing, Nothing)] .
How to proceed with strings but filtering files? Great thanks, Levi

Answer (score 0):

When working with [`StreamingContext.fileStream`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext), you have to explicitly specify the Hadoop Key type, Hadoop value type, and the incoming format. For example, if the key type is `Long`, you're receiving `Text` with an input format of `TextInputFormat`, you'd write:

```
val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/path/to/file")
               .map { case (key, text) => (key.toString, text.toString.split(" "))}
```

This would yield an `DStream[(String, Array[String)]`, where the `Array[String]` is your line after split.

Or if you only want the values you'd write:

```
val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/path/to/file")
               .map { case (_, text) => text.toString.split(" "))}
```

And you'd get a `DStream[Array[String]]`

### Edit

To apply the filter on the extension of the file you can, you can [Apache Commons IO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) - `FilenameUtils.getExtension`:

```
val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](
                  "/path/to/file", (file: Path) => 
                     FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.toString).equalsIgnoreCase("txt"))
               .map { case (_, text) => text.toString.split(" "))}
```

Comment: Great thanks, it works, but how to filter files by their names? That is my motive, which I possibly did not make explicit enough. Also for some reason "/path/to/file" was not enough, it expects something like new Sring("/path/to/file") or some other type. So, the question is how to add the file name filter? Thanks, again, Levi 
תודה

Comment: @Levi What doesn't work with the filter you provided?

Comment: I tried to follow your advice and wrote: 
val fstream = scc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](new String("""file:///C:\Users\lkitross\workspaceLuna\MyFirstScalaProject\""")); 
But I do not know how to add a filter on a file names in the folder. That is, how I am taking as an input stream only files "*.txt" and not "*.tst". Levi

Comment: I am new in Scala, so trivial things can be still difficult for me. (file: Path)  results in an error: not found type: path. I tried to add imports but it did not help or I did not find the correct one:  org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils, org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils, import java.io.File; and some others. Please, the last push... Levi

Comment: @Levi Did you `import java.nio.file.Path` ?

Comment: Finally succeeded with three departures:using import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path instead of import java.nio.file.Path.

Comment: Finally succeeded with three departures: `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` and not `import java.nio.file.Path`. Adding to fileStream additional Boolean parameter, and also removing one bracket 0 in: map { case (_, text) => text.toString.split(" ")}:
`val lines = scc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("""file:///pathWindows\dir\""", (file: Path) => FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.toString).equalsIgnoreCase("txt"),true);
 val words = lines.flatMap(  line => line._2.toString.split(" "));
val counts = words.map(word=>(word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _);`

Comment: similar question asked here by me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526228/spark-scala-streaming-csv

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/path/to/file")
               .map { case (key, text) => (key.toString, text.toString.split(" "))}` 
This code doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

An another solution :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
val fstream=scc.fileStream("""file:///pathToFolderWin""", (path: Path) => path.getName().endsWith(".txt"), true)
```