# Spark Scala Streaming CSV

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new in Spark/Scala. I know how to load CSV files:

```
    sqlContext.read.format("csv")
```

and how to read text streams and file streams:

```
    scc.textFileStream("""file:///c:\path\filename""");
    scc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](...)
```

but how to read text **stream in CSV** format? Thanks, Levi

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))


    // Create the FileInputDStream on the directory
    val lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///C:/foo/bar")

    lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
          println("RDD row count: " + rdd.count())
         // Now you can convert this RDD to DataFrame/DataSet and perform business logic.  

        }
      }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can stream your Csv file easily by using spark 2.2 structured streaming.

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198243/how-to-continuously-monitor-a-directory-by-using-spark-structured-streaming/46198303#46198303)